# A textedit with button?

Tags: android

I want to create a EditText and button that looks like this:

[http://www.geting.se/image.php/249016-Untitled-3.jpg/full http://www.geting.se/image.php/249016-Untitled-3.jpg/full](http://www.geting.se/image.php/249016-Untitled-3.jpg/full)

This is almost the same as the quicksearch , but it is custom made, 
Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to layout an EditText and a button next to each other, with 0 padding between them:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <EditText android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
   <Button android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

To get the curved corners on the outsides, but not the insides, you might need to define a new style for your EditText and Button.  See [applying styles and themes.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Typically, you need to create a background image using 9-patch to get the curved corners with proper scaling.  See [Draw 9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html)